# Purpose of the ATOMIC_INIT macro in the Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, c99

I'm reading the [Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/) book online and I'm having trouble understanding the initialization macro for [atomic variables](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-5-sect-7#chp-5-sect-7.2):

```
static atomic_t foobar = ATOMIC_INIT(1);
```

I've looked through the source code for the **Linux kernel v3.2**, but I've only come up with two definitions:

```
#define ATOMIC_INIT(i) { (i) }
```

and

```
#define ATOMIC_INIT(i) ((atomic_t) { (i) })
```

The second version of the definition for the macro seems to be functionally the same as the first -- in fact, it seems redundant to even have an explicit cast when the value would be implicitly cast anyway to `atomic_t`. Why are there two versions of the definition?

Is the purpose of the `ATOMIC_INIT` macro just to keep code from breaking if the `atomic_t` structure changes in a future release of the Linux kernel?

Comment: I can not find the second definition of the macro. In which file it is declared ?

Comment: A particular architecture may use one macro or the other. For example, **x86** machines use the first definition (located in [arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h?v=3.2#L15)), while **DEC Alpha** machines use the second definition (located in [arch/alpha/include/asm/atomic.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/alpha/include/asm/atomic.h?v=3.2#L17)). Check out this [link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.2&i=ATOMIC_INIT) for the various definitions.

Comment: In the second definition, this is not a cast, this is a compound literal which a completely different animal. In any case your "side question" shows that you first should look up how initialization works in C in contrast to assignment.

Comment: @JensGustedt I took your advice and read up on the differences between initialization and assignment; but I'm a still a bit confused on the purpose of using the compound literal over a regular initialization. From what I can understand, a compound literal is essentially an *anonymous* variable declaration and initialization. When using the `ATOMIC_INIT` macro, would the compound literal cause an assignment rather than an initialization; if not, what's the point of the compound literal in some architectures over others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many atomic operations must be implemented separately for each architecture.
The purpose of the various macros and functions in `atomic.h` is to hide the differences between architectures.

In practice, all architectures use a single 32-bit variable to implement `atomic_t`, so there is no practical difference in the various `ATOMIC_INIT` macros; all the interesting stuff happens in the operations.
But the internals might change (and *did* change once for 32-bit SPARC), so you always should use the offical API.

Comment: So while there currently is no practical difference between the `ATOMIC_INIT` macro, it's used as a provision for future changes to source code?

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two different forms of `ATOMIC_INIT` is that the first can only be used in initializations, the second can be used in initializations and assignments. At a first glance this sounds as if the second would be preferable, but it has an important use case where it can't be applied: block scope variables that are declared with `static` storage specification. In block scope

```
static atomic_t foobar = ((atomic_t) { (1) });
```

would be invalid for standard C, because the initializer would not be a compile time constant expression. (In file scope the compound literal would be statically allocated so it would work, there.)

I remember vaguely a discussion on the kernel list that mentioned that gcc has an extension that allows such code, and that this is one of the reasons they don't move on to C99 but stick to gnu89 as a C dialect.

Comment: Does that imply that some architecture specific source code in the kernel depends on the behavior of one definition as opposed to the other, and that's probably the reason behind of the two versions?

Comment: No, I suppose that what you see is a state in the middle of moving towards code that is more standards complying.

Comment: I believe you are correct, the more recent versions of `atomic.h` for the DEC Alpha architecture replaced the second version of the definition with the first.